# Default value in select parameter as DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying set default value of select parameter in MVC:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="PickDate" Type="DateTime"  DefaultValue="<%: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")%>" />
```

But it doesn't work... I got error":

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Can I set `DateTime.Now` to default value?

Edit1: Still doesn't work...

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDailyPickingList" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM DailyPickingList where PickDate = @PickDate">
     <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="PickDate" Type="DateTime"  DefaultValue="<%: DateTime.Now%>" />
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is it at all possible ?

Answer (score 5):

You are casting to string the default value when explicitly setting the type as DateTime. Try this:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="PickDate" Type="DateTime"  DefaultValue="<%: DateTime.Now%>" />
```

Or this

```
<asp:Parameter Name="PickDate" Type="string"  DefaultValue='<%: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")%>' />
```

Comment: the double quotes in your second example will cause a problem

Comment: So do you have some idea how to do that?

Comment: Well spotted @Les I have updated it to use simple quotes to avoid the error

Comment: What query is being executed? Have you profiled it? Using theDateTime approach will add time to your filter, which you probably don't want. Try the string approach

Comment: I added OnSelecting handler, and then I can see that in Value there is written exactly <%: DateTime.Now%>. Maybe I can't use this code there ?